# ICICI Payment Gateway Integration in Magento

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I get the Error:

```
Error Occured.
Error Code:2
Error Message: No response From Payment Gateway or URL not Found
```

during testing ICICI Payment Gateway in Magento in testssl.
Properties file contain the following line. Is it right or not ?

```
Key.Directory=/home/..../public_html/mg1/sbi/
```

Answer (score 3):

Please Open Postlib.php , go line no 716 .

Kindly change the slash on this line :-  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "\Sfa\cacert.pem");

For Windows it should be Backward slash curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "\Sfa\cacert.pem");

For Linux it should be Forward slash curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/Sfa/cacert.pem");

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem if any body face this problem. First if your OS is Linux then replace backslash with forward slash in PostLibPHP file and on line 27 in this file as $fp = fopen (realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/magento/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/testssl" ) ."//sfa.properties","r");

remove /magento or correct it so that given path point to correct testssp file path.

Answer (score 0):

Its most common issue with ICICI Gateway, you just need to keep in mind that you need to use Backward () **For Windows** and **Forward slash** (/) For Linux. rest will work well.